# Получить элемент в таблице HTML

Tags: javascript, html

У меня в таблице есть элементы select

```
<table id="create_disk_table" border="1" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="2">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <select name="data_center" id="data_centerList"></select>
    </td> 
   <td>
  <select name="domains" id="domainList"></select>
  </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Я пытаюсь обратиться к элементу select через javascrtipt

```
 let domains_list = document.getElementById("domainList");
```

вывод

```
undefined
```

Как правильно получить элемент?

Comment: А покажи как именно ты пытаешься вывести domains_list

Comment: И у тебя <tr> не закрытый

Comment: Если так делать, то все получается, я даже не поленился проверить))) проблема в чем-то другом, возможно асинхронный вызов или что-то подобное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. Это я рукожоп.
Вызов js функции был раньше, нежели я объявлял таблицу в html файле